# I am getting Error from For Loop function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

this is a function to call SELECT element values. but i am facing an error.
code is here.

```
function get_s_val(){
var foo = all_categories_1;
var ov1 = "";

    for(m=0;m<=foo.length;m++){
        ov1 += foo[m].value+',';
    }

console.log(ov1);
var tme=setTimeout("get_s_val()", 1000);
}
get_s_val();
```

it shows an error like `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"`

but when i do some littel changes it works.. like

```
function get_s_val(){
var foo = all_categories_1;
var ov1 = "";

    //for(m=0;m<=foo.length;m++){
        ov1 += foo[0].value+',';
    //}

console.log(ov1);
var tme=setTimeout("get_s_val()", 1000);
}
get_s_val();
```

i dont know that where i am wrong to write the code.

Comment: Why don't you use `var` for the loop variable, why do you pass a string to `setTimeout`?

Comment: what is all_categories_1 actually?

Comment: @soundar: all_categories_1 is a HTML SELECT element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your loop condition to run while the iterator is *less than* the length of the array, or you'll get `undefined` when you hit the non-existent element at index `foo.length`:

```
for(var m=0;m<foo.length;m++){
    ov1 += foo[m].value+',';
}
```

...and always declare variables with the `var` keyword, or bad things will happen, and JSLint will whine about it (and rightly so, but that's another topic).

Comment: Thanks Karim. it works. but tell me 1 thing, is "=<" or ">=" wrong thing to use.

Comment: If you want to iterate over all elements of an array, then yes. The first element of an array is at index `0`, so the last item is at `total number of elements - 1`. Hope that's clear.

Comment: yeh Karim, i know that rule.. but i just now understand that where was the problem. thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

```
function get_s_val(){
    var foo = all_categories_1;
    var ov1 = "";

        for(var m = 0; m < foo.length; m++){ // use var, and only loop from e.g.
                                             // 0 to 2 when the length is 3, so <,
                                             // not <=
            ov1 += foo[m].value+',';
        }

    console.log(ov1);

    setTimeout(get_s_val, 1000); // don't use a string, just pass the function.
                                 // Plus, the variable is nowhere accessible so
                                 // you can drop storing it
}

get_s_val();
```

Anyway, if you simply want to join the array's elements into a string with `,` as delimiter, why not do:

```
console.log(foo.join());
```

Comment: Thanks pimvdb for your answer and for join() function.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the `for` loop, `m<=foo.length;` should instead be `m<foo.length;`.

Comment: Thanks Hammerite for answering me.